# JS Math.random doesn't get -9-

Tags: javascript, random

The code is working for all the areas and figures, except when the variable id equals 9. Then the #10 image (#9 index) doesn't appear, an undefined message is written instead. When id equals any other number, the checkAnswer() function alert correct or wrong for every area clicked, except for the #10 area, which doesn't alert anything. What's wrong with the code? (the images are all correctly on the directory)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var cobras=new Array();

cobras[0] = '<img src="cobra1.jpg">';
cobras[1] = '<img src="cobra2.jpg">';
cobras[2] = '<img src="cobra3.jpg">';
cobras[3] = '<img src="cobra4.jpg">';
cobras[4] = '<img src="cobra5.jpg">';
cobras[5] = '<img src="cobra6.jpg">';
cobras[6] = '<img src="cobra7.jpg">';
cobras[7] = '<img src="cobra8.jpg">';
cobras[8] = '<img src="cobra9.jpg">';
cobras[9] = '<img src="cobra10.jpg">';
cobras[10] = '<img src="cobra11.jpg">';
cobras[11] = '<img src="cobra12.jpg">';
cobras[12] = '<img src="cobra13.jpg">';
cobras[13] = '<img src="cobra14.jpg">';
cobras[14] = '<img src="cobra15.jpg">';



id=Math.floor(Math.random()*15); 

function makeDisappear() {
var elem = document.getElementById("main");
elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
var elem = document.getElementById("empty");
elem.style.visibility = "visible";

var bodyE1 = document.body;
bodyE1.innerHTML += cobras[id];

}


function checkAnswer(a) {
if (a==id) {
    alert('Correct!')
    }
else {
    alert('Wrong!')
    }
}


</script>

</head>
<body>


<center> <button onclick="makeDisappear();"> Hide </button> </center>

<center> <img id="main" src="..\images\cobra.jpg" width="941" height="689" alt="Todos os bichos."> </center>
<center> <img style="visibility: hidden;" id="empty" src="..\images\vazio.jpg" width="941" height="689" alt="Vazio." usemap="#empty"> </center>


<map name="empty">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,230,190,40" alt="1" onclick="checkAnswer(1)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="191,230,380,40" alt="2" onclick="checkAnswer(2)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="381,230,570,40" alt="3" onclick="checkAnswer(3)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="571,230,760,40" alt="4" onclick="checkAnswer(4)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="761,230,941,40" alt="5" onclick="checkAnswer(5)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,470,190,240" alt="6" onclick="checkAnswer(6)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="191,470,380,240" alt="7" onclick="checkAnswer(7)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="381,470,570,240" alt="8" onclick="checkAnswer(8)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="571,470,760,240" alt="9" onclick="checkAnswer(9)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="761,470,941,689" alt="10" onclick="checkAnswer(10)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,490,190,689" alt="11" onclick="checkAnswer(11)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="191,490,380,689" alt="12" onclick="checkAnswer(12)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="381,490,570,689" alt="13" onclick="checkAnswer(13)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="571,490,760,689" alt="14" onclick="checkAnswer(14)">
  <area shape="rect" coords="761,490,941,689" alt="15" onclick="checkAnswer(15)">

</map>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Making all of your text bold doesn't make it more readable. What does the error message say? What line of code does it point to?

Comment: Sorry about that. And I'm really new to html, started yesterday actually. I didn't know that it was possible to correct it like python. I tried http://infohound.net/tidy/ now, but it said that there's no mistakes..

Comment: Open up your JS console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome, I don't know about Firefox with Firebug) and take a look at the errors. They should point to the line of code that generated them.

Comment: There is no error nor warning..

Comment: What happens when you click on 10? Also, are you sure that you're editing the right file?

Comment: Yes, definitely. It should alert either Correct! or Wrong!, but simply nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates in your `<area>` are correct?

Comment: Nope it wasn't. Since the image was also bugging, I didn't pay much attention to it. Still, now that I've changed it, all the areas and figures can be clicked and chosen, but the numbers of the images and the areas are completely off. I've changed the arguments in the checkAnswers to (0 - 14), but still, they're not related correctly.

Comment: Alright, it's good now. Thanks man!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is indeed only happening on item #9, it suggests to me some type of number verses string problem.

First change the variable name of 'id' to something else, that name could cause problems.

Then declare it at the top with a var, the same as you are doing with the cobras array.

I would change 'id' to a string, and convert the result of the Math function using parseInt.

Change the index values you are giving in the array to strings as well, so they become keys instead.

Then add single quotes around the value given in the checkAnswer calls from the area tags.

No guarantee that this would fix the problem, but at least you know for sure that the random item, and the item chosen, are all strings.

Comment: `Math.floor` returns an integer and `checkAnswer` is passed an integer, so the comparison is done between two integers. Also, property names on objects are automatically converted to strings, so `array['1']` and `array[1]` point to the same element.

Comment: I tried changing the name of "id" and using var before (although I've read that it wasn't necessary if it was in global scope). Nothing changed. And the single quotes around the checkAnswer were a previous problem that has been fixed by taking them out, so..